# Unregistered a computer with the domain controller using powershell?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, powershell

From what I understand when you add a computer to the domain, via `Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->System Properties->Computer Name->Network ID`, it gets registered with the Domain Controller.

When you switch the machine back to a workgroup, it un-registers the machine from the domain controller removing the machine from the domain.

Is there a way to remove / un-register a machine from the domain controller using powershell instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is is the `Remove-Computer` powershell command.

See technet for full details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849816%28v=wps.620%29.aspx

```
Parameter Set: Local
Remove-Computer [[-UnjoinDomainCredential] <PSCredential> ] [-Force] [-PassThru] [-Restart] [-Workgroup <String> ] [ <CommonParameters>]

Parameter Set: Remote
Remove-Computer -UnjoinDomainCredential <PSCredential> [-ComputerName <String[]> ] [-Force] [-LocalCredential <PSCredential> ] [-PassThru] [-Restart] [-Workgroup <String> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: This seems pretty good too: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-rename-a-domain-computer-with-windows-powershell/

Comment: well, you didn't say rename in your OP...but yeah, you can use the `rename-computer` cmdlet for that as well.